# Swift 2.0 - `nil` or `0` enum arguments

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

I've run into this a on a couple functions in Swift 2.0 and wondering if there is a work around. There seems to be no way to not specify enum arguments in Swift 2.0 now. For example, these two methods seem to require something other than `nil` or `0` be passed in. Is there a way around this?

```
// Cannot invoke '...' with argument list of type ... options: Int
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, fromDate: self.date, options: 0)
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: 0)

// Cannot invoke '...' with argument list of type ... options: nil
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, fromDate: self.date, options: nil)
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil)
```

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769387/swift-2-0-calendar-components-error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Options are now specified as a set, so just pass an empty set: `options: []`.

Comment: Well that was quick, thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed :)

Answer (score 9):

Just to add some more detail: the types in question, like NSJSONReadingOptions, are declared as `NS_OPTIONS` in Obj-C.

### Before Swift 2

Prior to Swift 2, these were imported to Swift as **RawOptionSetType**, which required BitwiseOperationsType and NilLiteralConvertible. This allowed you to pass `nil`, and to combine values with operators `a | b`, `a & ~b`, etc.

```
/// Protocol for `NS_OPTIONS` imported from Objective-C
protocol RawOptionSetType : BitwiseOperationsType, NilLiteralConvertible { ...

protocol BitwiseOperationsType {
    func &(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func |(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func ^(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    prefix func ~(x: Self) -> Self
    static var allZeros: Self { get }
}
```

### Nowadays

In Swift 2 it's been generalized a bit more. These are now **[OptionSetType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html)**, which requires SetAlgebraType and RawRepresentable. (The underlying `RawValue` type may or may not be BitwiseOperationsType.)

```
public protocol OptionSetType : SetAlgebraType, RawRepresentable {
    typealias Element = Self
    public init(rawValue: Self.RawValue)
}

public protocol SetAlgebraType : Equatable, ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    typealias Element
    public init()
    public func contains(member: Self.Element) -> Bool
    public func union(other: Self) -> Self
    public func intersect(other: Self) -> Self
    public func exclusiveOr(other: Self) -> Self
    // and more...
}
```

SetAlgebraType isn't NilLiteralConvertible anymore, but it is [ArrayLiteralConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ArrayLiteralConvertible_Protocol/index.html), so you can **use `[]` instead of `nil` to mean "no options"**.

And you can combine **multiple options in an array**: `options: [.MutableLeaves, .AllowFragments]`.

SetAlgebraType also has much more readable function names than those bitwise operators `&`, `|`, `^`, etc:

```
public func contains(member: Self.Element) -> Bool
public func union(other: Self) -> Self
public func intersect(other: Self) -> Self
public func exclusiveOr(other: Self) -> Self
```

So you can use `if jsonOptions.contains(.AllowFragments) { ...` and such.

Answer (score 0):

**You pass `[]` *(an empty set)***

Some `enums` have an explicit option that means `0`, but **Swift 3** sometimes do not import these, because `[]` means the same thing. Like `UIViewAutoresizing`'s `UIViewAutoresizingNone`

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and the accepted one?

Comment: It is more describing *(go more into depth)*. i.e. I was wondering why we have both sometimes. If you came for solution and do not care about context, accepted A is fine.